# Retrieving data from database using Nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, sqlite

I want to create a checkout page for my website and dynamically create a list of products that a user would have in their basket.

To do this I need to get the items they have from the database and use it in HTML.

I have SQLite3 set up in Nodejs and can insert data into it from forms in my website. I want to know what the best way is that I can reply the data back to the HTML page when the checkout webpage loads.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have to use SQLite3?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. No I don't, but it's the only database I've ever used, but I could easily switch. Would a different database make it easier?

Comment: In that case I would like to recommend you to try MongoDB with Mongoose ([link](http://mongoosejs.com/)). My experience is that Mongo is amazingly fast and easy to use. There's a getting started guide on the given link. Good luck!